# Dealing with external departments when changing to continous delivery / smaller feature scope

Tags: agile, process, development-process, process-engineering

I'm an engineer on a small engineering team at a small business-to-business company. We're looking to transition from a "big bang" release model to a more iterative release style with smaller changes going out in more frequent batches.

There is some concern that this could have a negative impact on other departments such as Customer Support, Sales, and Marketing because it would require more frequent updates to their documentation etc.

How can we make sure that a more iterative development process does not harm (or maybe helps) departments such as Customer Support, Sales, and Marketing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making sure you have cross functional teams. If there are sales or marketing actions that need to happen before release, then you need representatives *on the team* to make sure they happen on the right cadence.

Make a list of *all* the things that need to occur in order to release a feature. This is your “definition of done”. Do you have all the people and skills on the team to get them all done? If you don’t, you really need to work to bring those skills on board.

This is in direct opposition to how companies are traditionally organized, but it really is easier to ship product increments *sooner* if you can organize teams around products instead of by role function. The hierarchy doesn’t have to change, just what makes up a team.

Comment: So basically you make a cross functional team to solve a problem and if part of that problem involves sales/marketing/support functions you add members to the team that help with those functions?

Comment: That’s what works *best* in my experience, but it’s a hard sell. Most folks in “the business” think “that agile stuff” is just for the software developers.